# How to reliably access dynamically assigned attribute values from a separate directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm writing an Angular directive to wrap a third party plugin I want to use in my application. The plugin needs to read the classes assigned to the element I'm using my custom directive on. I'm able to access the class attribute fine when doing static class assignment in the markup; but if I use `ngClass` to assign an additional class dynamically to my element, it is invisible to my custom directive.

I have written up a simple plunkr to demonstrate the issue below:

http://plnkr.co/edit/i5iBwlKXuvrdjF85wiIU?p=preview

But the thrust of it is contained here:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl"> 
  <div class="staticAssignment"
    ng-class="cssClass"
    my-directive>
  </div>
</body>
```

and:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.cssClass = 'dynamicAssignment';
});

app.directive("myDirective", function () {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
      console.log("my classes: ", element.attr('class'))
    }
  };
});
```

When the directive's `link` function executes, I expect it to log:
`"staticAssignment dynamicAssignment"`,
but the dynamically assigned class is not seen at the time of linking.

Wrapping the content of my `link` function in a `$timeout` resolves this, but it still raises the question: is there a reliable way to define the order in which your various directives are evaluated on a given element? Ideally I'd want `myDirective` to explicitly wait for `ngClass` to finish its jazz before going through with its own actions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can watch the expression in `attr.ngClass` and do the printing in the listener.  With the way `ngClass` is currently implemented, this approach works regardless of which `priority` you gives your directive.

```
app.directive("myDirective", function () {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
      scope.$watch(attr.ngClass, function(val) {
        console.log("my classes: ", element.attr('class'))  
      });
    }
  };
});
```

[Demo link](http://plnkr.co/edit/THPEgVySO8mDdi8jQnuy?p=preview)

Comment: This worked like a charm. Do you have any advice on getting it to work in conjunction with `ngRepeat`? e.g. watching class assignment on elements created by the repeat directive?

Comment: It should work the same way, see this http://plnkr.co/edit/9A56Zz58O3VporsDGDKJ?p=preview. Or do you mean s/t else (a plunker would help)?

Comment: i.e. http://plnkr.co/edit/4Pi6JGbRXZYC5ghhRaFx?p=preview . `myDirective` needs to know when a "size-" class has been assigned to the elements produced by `ngRepeat` in order to perform appropriate calls to a third party plugin.

Comment: The plunker you provided prints out just fine, what do you expect it to print?

Answer (score 1):

So after much research, I have come to the conclusion that `class` is a special case attribute that cannot be tracked/watched with the current api (`ngClass` can be watched, see Buu Nguyen's answer). Allow me to document the steps of my discovery.

First I checked the angular documentation and found this snippet:

> The Attributes object - passed as a parameter in the link() or compile() functions - is a way of accessing:
>
> ...
>
> - directive inter-communication: All directives share the same instance
>     of the attributes object which allows the directives to use the
>     attributes object as inter directive communication.
> - observing interpolated attributes: Use $observe to observe the value changes of attributes that contain interpolation (e.g.
>     src="{{bar}}"). Not only is this very efficient but it's also the only
>     way to easily get the actual value because during the linking phase
>     the interpolation hasn't been evaluated yet and so the value is at
>     this time set to undefined.

So I figured that `attr.$observe('class', function(value) {})` was the answer you needed. To my surprise, this failed to work!

I proceeded to examine the source code for 1.2.0-rc2 for the problem. I found that the `attr` object contains a function called `$set` that is used to set attribute values and fire the observer functions. Unfortunately, `ngClass` does not call `$set` when it changes the value of the `class` attribute, it calls `attr.$addClass/$removeClass`. These other methods don't fire the observers like one might expect, and instead directly call `element.addClass` in `$animate`. The same issue exists in the 1.0.8 release, just without the call to `$animate`.

What is funny is that `ngClass` has a `attr.$observe('class', ...` in it's implementation, but that observer will only ever be called if someone outside of angular calls `$set('class', ..`.

I imagine this is because the class attribute of an element is likely changing often, and firing all those observers all the time is a waste of resources. Luckily, Buu Nguyen has an answer for your particular case ;).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed research. I tried `attr.$observe('class', function () {});` myself at some point after reading other threads touting the power of `$observe` and saw it didn't work for my case, inexplicably. Your spelunking into the source reveals why that is.

Comment: `class` isn't a special case at all. Try adding some interpolated text to it, e.g. class="{{scopeExp}}" and you'll see observers invoked. The document you quoted also states that pretty clear, isn't it? "Use $observe to observe the value changes of attributes that contain interpolation (e.g. src="{{bar}}")"

Comment: @BuuNguyen I suppose you are right, it's just not what I expected since the ngClass also uses the attr object to modify the classes and the attr object is also used for interdirective communication. Just seems inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

did you try setting the  priority attribute of the directive?

> priority - When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element, sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives are applied. The priority is used to sort the directives before their compile functions get called. Priority is defined as a number. Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first. The order of directives with the same priority is undefined. The default priority is 0.

from the angular docs.

Comment: Yes, I did try this, setting the priority of my custom directive to a negative value. However, I don't think this is the intention of `priority` -- the apps suggest it is limited to designating the order in which the directives' `compile` functions are called, rather than the `link` functions.